# Slice JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to `slice()` JavaScript object?

Assuming I have an object `x = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}` how do I chop off its first attribute (just like I would do with `.slice(1)` method upon array), so I get `x = {b:2, c:3, d:4}`?

Same question has been raised over here several times (dated back to few years ago) but none of them got answer, which delivers exactly the solution I need and seem old-fashioned as of today.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "first attribute" in an object. Objects are unordered so every key has as much claim to being "first" as every other key. Any solution you come up with has a chance of removing any single element from the object depending on the JavaScript engine/implementation you're running it on.

Comment: How would you know that `a` is the first item ? Object properties aren't guarateed to have an order. You can only do this if you find any criteria that can order items by name. Do property names have an alphabetic order ? If  not, is there any order criteria you can guess ?

Comment: Objects have no data ordering, so what would a "slice" even mean?

Comment: FYI: since ES2015 order is guaranteed as insertion order (unless they parse as ints apparently).

Comment: @rlemon That is incorrect.

Comment: @user11278349 Is that what you want ? slice the first object using insertion order ?

Comment: @rlemon they are most certainly not, instead you get to pick between [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) if you want to be more explicit about what your object is without writing your own class, with `Set` being the "unique, but not ordered" version, and `Map` being the "ordered, but not unique" version.

Comment: Object.entries doesn't care about creation order, this is true (also TIL). But please show me that object keys are not ordered today as insertion order.

Comment: @rlemon is correct. [Traversal order of object properties is well-defined in ES2015.](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/). This includes `Object.entries` but *not* `Object.keys`, for backwards compatibility reasons. (The linked article includes links and references to the ES2015 spec as well as other resources.)

Comment: In my code I have those objects uniform (with properties order always the same) so slicing them is what crossed my mind first.

Comment: @JordanRunning however, note that the text immediately shows a case that violates insertion order due to how integer indices get pulled up in the ordering. So keys are _still_ not guaranteed to be ordered the way your code declared them.

Comment: @user11278349 and about the order criteria ? Can you find a property name order criteria ? is it alphabetic ?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yep. It's a good article in that regard. (Perhaps I should have said "@rlemon is correct except in specific circumstances which are described in this article blah blah blah..." You can't please everybody all the time.)

Comment: No, but you can say "object keys are in fact still not guaranteed ordered the way you declared them. Only string keys are", which is a big enough exception to justify being clear about the fact that anyone's claims that using es2015+ functions yield Object keys exactly the way you defined them, is demonstrably false. It _cannot_ be relied on. (what you _can_ rely on is that using ES2015+ functions there at least _is_ an order, and so the same call will yield the same ordering every time, which pre-ES2015 wasn't a guarantee in the slightest)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans bottom line: don't do this.

Comment: Please see @Paulpro comments in Yevgen Gorbunkov's answer. They're relevant to the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer depends heavily in the lack of a defined key order criteria in the question. If a key order is defined, a solution becames easy as a conversion or sort algorithm can be created to process the keys in the determined order.**

As the lengthy discussion in comments have proven conclusively, since the question didn't explicit a criteria for the order of the keys, there's no safe way to guaratee that an element sliced by any method, will indeed be what is considered by a human observer as "the first element".

The [article](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/) mentioned by @JordanRunning already states that keys with integer values or integer convertable values are put as the first elements.

After that @Paulpro mentioned that Object.getOwnPropertyNames and Reflect.ownKeys have the a guaranteed order but Object.keys and Object.entries don't have a guaranteed order since ES6.

If the elements are just these 4 keys in the question an answer that used Object.getOwnPropertyNames or Reflect.ownKeys would be possible once the order is guarateed to be chronological for string keys. But once we don't know if there will be a property with an integer (or integer convertible) name or even what happens after `z` element there's no conclusive answer to this.

For example: let's say the object keys are initially alphabetical. What happens after z ? the next key is aa, ab, etc ? if yes ok... but there are so many other possibilites... what if after z came 1 ? or if this is in cyrilic that has non-standard characters? portuguese for example has accented letters which for some sort algorithms come after all other letters. So you have A that comes first and Á that goes after Z. What if the algorithm that created the object ordered it wrongly because of this and the chronological order got wrong ?

Bottom-line: not possible using objects. Use Map, arrays or any other solution instead or define the key order as alredy stated.

Answer (score -3):

Use can solve this by using the slice and map function

```
    var obj = {0: 'zero', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four'};

 var result = Object.keys(obj).slice(0,2).map(key => ({[key]:obj[key]})); 

console.log(result);
```

Then it will result

```
[ { '0': 'zero' }, { '1': 'one' } ]
```

Comment: You mean it might result in that in some implementations of JavaScript.

Comment: So he didn't need the ans in javascript??

Comment: He need's a correct answer (or just a comment and a close vote), which is to use a Map instead of an object if order is desired. It is meaningless to slice an object in JavaScript.